# .Net DataTable sorting/ordering by amount

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I've tried many searches for ordering a DataTable based on a column and all searches only return results for either sorting or ordering the actual columns. I'm hoping to get a DataTable by incremental order but can only return results similar to:

```
DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Integer asc";
DataTable= DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();


<DataTable>
  <Integer>159</Integer>
  <String>TextData</String>
</DataTable>
<DataTable>
  <Integer>16</Integer>
  <String>TextData</String>
</DataTable>
<DataTable>
  <Integer>163</Integer>
  <String>TextData</String>
</DataTable
```

Comment: I suppose I could try using a string datatype and adding leading zeros to see if it sorts correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible a better solution would be to set the `DataType` of the columns when you add them to the `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataTable");
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] 
{
    new DataColumn("Integer", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("String", typeof(string))
});
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Integer asc";
dt.ReadXml("xmlfile3.xml");
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```